# Add pandas count column if present in list by partial and case insensitive match

Tags: pandas

I want to add a column of counting number of occurances of each element in pandas column by partial string matching and ignoring case, against the list. 
my input dataframe is `foo`
I want to match against list `mylist`

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : ['hi', 'foo', 'at']})

mylist = ['oo', 'fat', 'cat']
```

So, I want to add a column in the dataframe `foo`, of count of each element in column `b` if it is present in `mylist`. I want to check the matching by ignoring case and partial matching.

The expected result in case above should be,

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : ['hi', 'foo', 'at'], 'count': [0, 1, 2]})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and test with `in` and `sum` of `True` values:

```
#if necessary convert list values to lowercase
#mylist = [x.lower() for x in mylist]
foo['count'] = foo['b'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: sum((x in y) or (y in x) for y in mylist))
print (foo)
   a    b  count
0  1   hi      0
1  2  foo      1
2  3   at      2
```